# How to have obSubmit and onChange events for file upload in form in react, material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm building a React component which is a simple. It has `Upload` button which upload a file. I can't get `onSumbit` to fire off in my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/es/Typography/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/es/Button/Button';
import { UploadCSVstyles } from '../styles/Material-UI/muiStyles.js';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/es/styles/withStyles';

import * as log from 'loglevel';
log.setLevel("debug");

class UploadCSV extends React.Component {
  state = {
    uploadedFile: null
  }

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    log.debug('from submit');
    this.setState({
      uploadedFile: e.target.files[0]
    });
  }

  onChange = e => {
    log.debug('from change');
    this.setState({
      uploadedFile: e.target.files[0]
    });
  }

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography>
          You can upload a CSV file containing app id's in one columns.
        </Typography>
        <input
          accept="text/csv"
          className={classes.input}
          id="contained-button-file"
          multiple
          type="file"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={classes.button}>
            Choose files
          </Button>
        </label>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={classes.button}
                  type="submit">
            Upload
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

UploadCSV.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default UploadCSV;
```

The problem is I think with Material-UI button because it somehow doesn't trigger `onSubmit`.
How do I make the `onSubmit` event work with Material-UI `Button`?

Comment: Do you want to fire the `submit` event after your file is changed without waiting for the `Upload` button click? Or fire it only when you click the `Upload` button?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1bqxqj

Comment: @Colin I don't see the code for `Choose files` button in your code

Comment: @Colin I'm not getting any error I just can't get `onSubmit` to fire

Comment: the problem was that in `Upload` button I needed to remove `component` prop.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code. Cool, glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

in contrast to your above code, in functional component it is quite easy to implement. The only trick is to pass your onSubmit() method to your component as props. Here is how to do it;

```
// From where component is called 

const componentCalled = () => {

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        // do something here
    }

    return (
        <myComponent handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    )
}
```

and your component may look like;

```
const MyComponent = ({handleSubmit}) => {
    return (
        <Button variant="contained" component="span" className={classes.button}
                 onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Upload
          </Button>
    )
}
```